# Get workflow tasks from Documentum

Tags: workflow, business-process-management, documentum

Getting documents from [Documentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentum) is easy (for instance via its CMIS API).

But how to get Documentum's **workflow tasks**?
I mean the tasks that are currently active and assigned to the current user.
My code will live in a client app, so it must performs requests to the Documentum server remotely.

CMIS does not expose workflow tasks, so I guess using another API is needed?
The more maintainable the better.

Comment: which version of Documentum platform are you interested?

Comment: @Miki: I always work on the latest release.

Comment: Then you have REST API available. Since you are mentioning workflows there is big chance that you use xCP2.x platform. There you you basically have API for every action with you could do using OOTB client application or so. btw your question is where broad, please narrow it with tags and more detailed description

Comment: @Miki: Thanks! Would you mind posting an answer using REST? I searched in http://www.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu7122.pdf it shows how to instantiate a workflow but does not say how to get the current user's tasks. I added relevant tags I could find, and described more.

Comment: you linked documentation to DFS. It's an older and not very popular way of interactiong with Documentum these days.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 7.0 (and afterwards released 6.7 SP2 version of Documentum REST API) you have option to use [REST API](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-32266) to access Documentum platform.

From the link:

*EMC Documentum REST Services is a set of RESTful web service interfaces to interact with the Documentum platform. Being developed in a purely RESTful style, EMC Documentum REST Services is hypertext-driven, server-side stateless, and content negotiable, which provides you with high efficiency, simplicity, and makes all services easy to consume.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if CMIS can execute arbitrary DQL statements, but if it is able to, you can get the list of tasks and information about single task by using DQL query. The problem is you cannot do anything with the task (acquire, complete, delegate, etc) if CMIS has no support for such operations.
The other way is to use Documentum Foundation Classes (DFC) or Documentum Foundation Services.

Comment: CMIS can not execute arbitrary DQL statements.

Comment: My question is more about protocols other than CMIS, as I know it is not possible via CMIS.

Comment: If you have Java environment, the first idea might be to use DFC.